# Is this ring extension flat?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra. Let $B=A[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be the polynomial ring over $A$ and let $I \subseteq B$ be an ideal such that $B/I$ is flat over $A$. Let $f_1, \ldots, f_r \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and let $J \subseteq B$ be the ideal generated by $I$ and the $f_j$. Is it true that $B/J$ is then also flat over $A$?

edit: Mohan pointed out that the answer is trivially "no". Does the following assumption change anything: $A\cap J=(0)$ and the $f_j$ are linear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. Why did you expect that? For example, consider, say $A$ is a domain and $B=A[x]$, $I=(x-a)B$ for some $0\neq a\in A$. Then the natural map $A\to B/I$ is an isomorphism and in particular flat. If $J=I+xB$, clearly $A\to B/J=A/aA$ is not flat.

Comment: Oh, you are right, stupid question. The situation I was thinking about satisfies $A\cap J=(0)$ (and the $f_j$ are linear). Does this change anything?

Comment: Not really. Consider $A=k[t,u]$, polynomial ring in 2 variables and $n=2$. Take $I$ to be the principal ideal generated by $tx_1-u+x_2$. Then $B/I$ is flat over $A$. But, $J=I+x_2B$ will have $B/J$ not flat over $A$, though $A\cap J=0$.